# string does not pass to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to post my string called 'selected' trough my $.ajax call but the controller(selected=null) receives a null value? selected has a value ({'selected':0100}) according to fiddler?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string selected)
{
    return Json(new {value = "this is a test"});
}

$(document).ready(
     $("#btnSave").click(
         function () {
         var checkboxesselected = "0100";

         $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
             url: "/Home/Index",
             datatype: 'json',
             data: "{'selected':" + checkboxesselected + "}"
         });
     }
)
```

Comment: "{'selected':'" + checkboxesselected + "'}" ? (add single quotes on value)

Comment: Not submitting as an answer because this is only a vague recollection and I can't test right now... try wrapping checkboxesselected in quotes, so you'd send `{'selected': '0100'}`. I remember running into this problem several times a few months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're sending the data to jQuery as a string literal as opposed to an object. Your line with the data parameters should be `data: {selected: checkboxesselected }`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var val = { selected: checkboxesselected };
```

and then:
...

```
datatype: 'json',
data: val
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the quotes around "checkboxesselected "

```
$(document).ready(
    $("#btnSave").click(
        function () {
        var checkboxesselected = "0100";

        $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/Index",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: "{ 'selected' : '" + checkboxesselected + "'}"
        });
    }
)
```